# Fortran arrays in Julia callbacks

Tags: arrays, callback, fortran, julia

I am trying to write a wrapper for twpbvpc (ODE BVP with remeshing) Fortran-77 solver. The solver needs the input function with signature

```
subroutine fsub(ncomp, x, u, f, rpar, ipar)
```

where

- `ncomp` is an integer (length of the vector),
- `x` (in) is a float,
- `u` (in) is a vector of length `ncomp`,
- `f` (out) is the location for the result, vector of length `ncomp`
- `rpar` and `ipar` are arrays of float and integer external parameters; Julia's closure would be more preferred way, but apparently there are difficulties with it (see [the blog post here](http://julialang.org/blog/2013/05/callback)). But for a moment they can be ignored.

In Julia, to write `fsub` I would normally use the signature

```
function fsub_julia(x :: Float64, y :: Vector{Float64}, dy :: Vector{Float64})
        dy[1] = ...
        dy[2] = ...
        ...
end
```

`ncomp` doesn't seem to be necessary as can get the length via `length` or `size` (however, can Julia detect the size of the passed arrays from Fortran? for a test code, I know `ncomp` explicitly, so for now it's not a problem).

So, to comply with twpbvpc format I wrote a wrapper:

```
function fsub_par(n :: Int64, x :: Float64, y :: Vector{Float64}, dy :: Vector{Float64}, rpar :: Vector{Float64}, ipar :: Vector{Float64})
        fsub_julia(x, y, dy)
end
```

Now, to pass this function to Fortran routine, it needs to be converted using `cfunction` to declare the types. The question is how?

If I put it as:

```
cf_fsub = cfunction(fsub_par, Void, (Ref{Int64}, Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64}, Ref{Int64}))
```

When called from Fortran, I get the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (::TWPBVP.#fsub_par#1{TWPBVP_Test.#f})(::Int64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  fsub_par(::Int64, ::Float64, !Matched::Array{Float64,1}, !Matched::Array{Float64,1}, !Matched::Array{Float64,1}, !Matched::Array{Float64,1})
```

So, somehow the signature doesn't match for the array arguments...

If I replace `Ref{Float64}` for an array arguments with `Ref{Array{Float64,1}}` (it does look a bit odd though...):

```
cf_fsub = cfunction(fsub_par, Void, (Ref{Int64}, Ref{Float64}, Ref{Array{Float64,1}}, Ref{Array{Float64,1}}, Ref{Array{Float64,1}}, Ref{Array{Int64,1}}))
```

I get a segmentation fault at the point when `fsub_par` (`cf_fsub`) is called in Fortran code (this located approximately, as the error doesn't give exact location).

Replacing `Ref{Float54}` with `Ptr{Float64}` for arrays also doesn't do anything.

One interesting thing I found in the Fortran code is how `fsub` is called:

```
call fsub (ncomp, xx(1), u(1,1), fval(1,1),rpar,ipar)
```

where `u` and `fval` are declared as:

```
dimension xx(nmsh), u(nudim,nmsh), fval(ncomp,nmsh)
```

So, I guess, it uses the fact that Fortran passes all the arguments by reference and reference to `u(1,1)` is supposed to be the pointer to the first column of the matrix (as far as I remember Fortran, as Julia, stores matrices in column-first order).

What is the way out of it? Do I need to change the signature of `fsub_julia` to accept the pointers and convert them to arrays manually (this is how [ODEInterface.jl](https://github.com/luchr/ODEInterface.jl) works at the lower level)?

### Update

Following how it was done in ODEInterface.jl and combining with the idea of passing Julia's functions in `void*`-thunk parameters in C I came up with this:

```
immutable TWPBVPCProblem
    fsub :: Function            # RHS function
    dfsub :: Function           # Jacobian of RHS
    gsub :: Function            # BC function
    dgsub :: Function           # gradients of BC function
end

function unsafe_fsub(rn :: Ref{Int64}, rx :: Ref{Float64}, py :: Ptr{Float64}, pdy :: Ptr{Float64}, rpar :: Ptr{Float64}, ipar :: Ptr{Int64}) :: Void
    x = rx[]
    n = rn[]
    y = unsafe_wrap(Array, py, n)
    dy = unsafe_wrap(Array, pdy, n)
    problem = unsafe_pointer_to_objref(rpar) :: TWPBVPCProblem
    problem.fsub(x, y, dy)
    return nothing
end

const fsub_ptr = cfunction(unsafe_fsub, Void, (Ref{Int64}, Ref{Float64}, Ptr{Float64}, Ptr{Float64}, Ptr{Float64}, Ptr{Int64}))
```

And when I call the solver I do (it's rather long):

```
function twpbvpc(nlbc :: Int64,
        aleft :: Float64, aright :: Float64,
        fixpnt :: Nullable{Vector{Float64}},
        ltol :: Vector{Int64}, tol :: Vector{Float64},
        linear :: Bool, givmsh :: Bool, giveu :: Bool, nmsh :: Ref{Int64},
        xx :: Vector{Float64}, u :: Array{Float64, 2}, nmax :: Ref{Int64},
        wrk :: Vector{Float64}, iwrk :: Vector{Int64},
        fsub :: Function, dfsub :: Function,
        gsub :: Function, dgsub :: Function,
        ckappa1 :: Ref{Float64}, gamma1 :: Ref{Float64},
        ckappa :: Ref{Float64},
        # rpar :: Vector{Float64},
        # ipar :: Vector{Int64},
        iflbvp :: Ref{Int64})

    # Keep problem functions in rpar
    # HACK!
    rpar = TWPBVPCProblem(fsub, dfsub, gsub, dgsub)

    # Fake external parameters
    # Can't have it 0-length as it would be Any[0] and not Float64[0]
    # local rpar :: Vector{Float64} = [0.0]
    local ipar :: Vector{Int64} = [0]

    # No need to pass these parameters
    # u is a matrix for the solution only!
    ncomp, nucol = size(u)
    # Get the maximum of xx
    nxxdim = length(xx)
    # max for mesh points must be the same as the number of column points of u
    assert(nucol == nxxdim)

    # Sizes of work arrays
    lwrkfl = length(wrk)
    lwrkin = length(iwrk)

    # Number of fixed mesh points
    if isnull(fixpnt)
        nfxpnt = 0
        fixpnt_v = [0.0]
    else
        fixpnt_v = get(fixpnt)
        nfxpnt = length(fixpnt_v)
    end

    # Size of tolerance vector ≤ ncomp
    ntol = length(ltol)

    ccall((:twpbvpc_, libtwpbvpc), Void,
        (Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64},                    # ncomp, nlbc,
        Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64},                 # aleft, aright
        Ref{Int64}, Ptr{Float64},                   # nfxpnt, fixpnt
        Ref{Int64}, Ptr{Int64}, Ptr{Float64},       # ntol, ltol, tol
        Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64},         # linear, givmsh, giveu
        Ref{Int64}, Ref{Int64},                     # nmsh, nxxdim
        Ptr{Float64}, Ref{Int64},                   # xx, nudim
        Ptr{Float64}, Ref{Int64},                   # u, nmax
        Ref{Int64}, Ptr{Float64},                   # lwrkfl, wrk
        Ref{Int64}, Ptr{Int64},                     # lwrkin, iwrk
        Ptr{Void}, Ptr{Void}, Ptr{Void}, Ptr{Void}, # fsub, dfsub, gsub, dgsub
        Ref{Float64}, Ref{Float64},                 # ckappa1, gamma1
        Ref{Float64}, Any, Ptr{Int64},              # ckappa, rpar, ipar
        Ref{Int64}),                                # iflbvp
        ncomp, nlbc, aleft, aright,
        nfxpnt, fixpnt_v, ntol, ltol, tol,
        linear, givmsh, giveu, nmsh,
        nxxdim, xx, nucol, u, nmax,                 # nudim = nucol
        lwrkfl, wrk, lwrkin, iwrk,
        fsub_ptr, dfsub_ptr, gsub_ptr, dgsub_ptr,
        ckappa1,gamma1,ckappa,pointer_from_objref(rpar),ipar,iflbvp)
end
```

The Fortran's `twpbvpc` looks like this (the beginning obviously):

```
  subroutine twpbvpc(ncomp, nlbc, aleft, aright,
 *       nfxpnt, fixpnt, ntol, ltol, tol,
 *       linear, givmsh, giveu, nmsh,
 *       nxxdim, xx, nudim, u, nmax,
 *       lwrkfl, wrk, lwrkin, iwrk,
 *       fsub, dfsub, gsub, dgsub,
 *       ckappa1,gamma1,ckappa,rpar,ipar,iflbvp)

  implicit double precision (a-h,o-z)
  dimension rpar(*),ipar(*)
  dimension fixpnt(*), ltol(*), tol(*)
  dimension xx(*), u(nudim,*)
  dimension wrk(lwrkfl), iwrk(lwrkin)

  logical linear, givmsh, giveu
  external fsub, dfsub, gsub, dgsub

  logical pdebug, use_c, comp_c
  common/algprs/ nminit, pdebug, iprint, idum, uval0, use_c, comp_c
  ...
```

Fortran code is compiled with `build.jl`:

```
cd(joinpath(Pkg.dir("TWPBVP"), "deps"))
pic = @windows ? "" : "-fPIC"
run(`gfortran -m$WORD_SIZE -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-integer-8 -ffixed-form $pic -shared -O3 -o libtwpbvpc.so twpbvpc.f`)
```

So, I'm passing `rpar` as `Any` (should be equivalent to `Ptr{Void}`): Fortran expects an array of floating-point numbers though, but it shouldn't matter.

Now I'm getting segmentation fault when I try to run a simple program (on `Pkg.test("TWPBVP")`):

```
signal (11): Segmentation fault
while loading /home/alexey/.julia/v0.5/TWPBVP/test/runtests.jl, in expression starting on line 58
unknown function (ip: 0xffffffffffffffff)
Allocations: 1400208 (Pool: 1399373; Big: 835); GC: 0
```

As the code is getting very long, here is the link to the full code on github: https://github.com/mobius-eng/TWPBVP.jl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I need to change the signature of fsub_julia to accept the pointers and convert them to arrays manually (this is how ODEInterface.jl works at the lower level)?

Yes, the ODEInterface.jl model looks like a pretty good one to follow.

The first thing you need to find out is the size of your fortran `INTEGER` type (either `Int32` or `Int64`). For the code below I'll borrow from ODEInterface.jl and use `FInt` (it could either be a type parameter, or a `typealias`)

The resulting fallback should look something like:

```
# SUBROUTINE FSUB(NCOMP,X,Z,F,RPAR,IPAR)
# IMPLICIT NONE
# INTEGER NCOMP, IPAR
# DOUBLE PRECISION F, Z, RPAR, X
# DIMENSION Z(*),F(*)
# DIMENSION RPAR(*), IPAR(*)
function unsafe_fsub(ncomp::Ref{FInt}, x::Ref{Float64}, z::Ptr{Float64}, 
        f::Ptr{Float64}, rpar::Ptr{Float64}, ipar::Ptr{FInt})::Void
    xx = x[]
    zz = unsafe_wrap(Array, z, ncomp[])
    ff = unsafe_wrap(Array, f, ncomp[])
    fsub!(xx, zz, ff) # function which updates array ff
    return nothing
end

const fsub_ptr = cfunction(unsafe_fsub, Void,
    (Ref{FInt},Ref{Float64},Ptr{Float64},Ptr{Float64},Ptr{Float64},Ptr{FInt}))
```

Comment: I did `-fdefault-integer-8` in compiler option to make sure integers are Julia's `Int64`. Here is a bit crazy idea: can I use `rpar` or `ipar` in Fortran the same way I can use `void *`-kind parameter in C to pass the closure (see the link to the blog post in the question)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean: `rpar` and `ipar` are parameters from the fortran program, so how could they be a closure?

Comment: These are "use defined" parameters, Fortran routines just pass them around and pass them into the call to `fsub`, never write or read into them. So, whatever I put in there, it will be there, I just need to grab a pointer. See "Passing closures in data structures" in http://julialang.org/blog/2013/05/callback

Comment: What version of Julia? Can you post the output in a gist?

Comment: That might work, but no guarantee. You would want to use `pointer_from_objref` and `unsafe_pointer_to_objref`, see, e.g. RCall.jl: https://github.com/JuliaInterop/RCall.jl/blob/master/src/callback.jl#L108

Comment: Version 0.5, the output is just `unknown function (ip: 0xffffffffffffffff)`, this time doesn't even give me the location of error. Maybe I should update the question to make it a bit clearer what I'm doing.

Comment: Yes that would be useful

Comment: I've updated the question and published the full code on github https://github.com/mobius-eng/TWPBVP.jl

Comment: Can you update the repo with your attempt at the above?

Comment: Also, you can't create `cfunction`s of functions inside functions (which is the point about closures you refer to)

Comment: Done, the call to `cfunction` is now in global scope